# Use AngularJS in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to populate a popup with some user information using ng-repeat. The controller is not being even called from the pop up page. I dont know what I`m doing wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction please. Here is the code to understand better.

**app.js**

```
.state('SelectProfile', {
          url: "/profile/selectprofile/operation:operation&ProfileId:ProfileId",
          template: "",
          views: {
              "tabView": {
                  templateUrl: function (params) { return '/Admin/Profile/Index?id=' + params.id; },
                  controller: 'profileControllerList', onExit: function () {
                      $('#loading-spinner-container').show();
                      alert("hadem");
                  }
              },
              "tabTop": {
                  templateUrl: function (params) { return '/admin/profile/view/' + params.id; },
              }
          }
              , controller: 'profileController',
          onExit: function () {
              $('.loading-spinner-container').show();
          }
      })
```

**controllers.js**

```
controller('selectProfilesController', ['$scope', '$http', 'DataServices', 'usSpinnerService', '$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $http, DataServices, usSpinnerService, $stateParams) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        DataServices.getProfiles().then(function (successResult) {
            alert("ma nafx");
            $scope.ProfileObjects = successResult.data;
            $('#loading-spinner-container,.loading-spinner-container').hide();
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    }
]);
```

**Pop up page**

```
<tr ng-repeat="prof in ProfileObjects | filter:FirstName.LastName">
                    <td>
                        {{prof.Photo}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{prof.FirstName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{prof.LastName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{prof.CurrentCompanyName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{prof.CurrentTitle}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ng-show="!prof.IsDeleted"></span>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Select", "SelectedProfile", new { operation = ViewBag.Operation, Id = 1, CompanyId = ViewBag.CompanyId, ProfileId = ViewBag.ProfileId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" })
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: You might be routing your call to ASP.NET MVC controller.plz check. Instead you should call a method on the AngularJS controller using ng-click

Comment: ok i called the angularjs controller using ng-click now i cant populate the popup using ng-repeat. it seams like that the profileobject is still empty

Comment: You need to set the ProfileObjects on the model in the controller

Comment: I ve done the following code:


`controller('appController', ['$scope', '$http', 'DataServices', 'usSpinnerService', '$stateParams',
    function ($scope, $http, DataServices, usSpinnerService, $stateParams) {
        $scope.removePlayer = function() {
            DataServices.getProfiles().then(function (successResult) {
                $scope.ProfileObjects = successResult.data;
                $("#btnTriggerTest").trigger('click');
                console.log($scope.ProfileObjects);
            });
        }
    }
]);`

Sorry for the bad formating but I cant make the `` work :/

Comment: can you share the detail code. like how are you opening the popup. If you are using the model in the popup then you need to pass the model ProfileObjects when you are trying to open the popup.